# Base de Datos no conecta con variable de ambiente en ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo un problema con el archivo de variables de ambiente, realmente no veo el problema y tengo horas y horas y nada, si alguien me puede ayudar sería genial.

La situación es la siguiente:

Tengo una archivo de variables de ambiente llamado  config/variables_de_ambiente.yml con el siguiente código:

```
development:
  DB_USUARIO: user
  DB_CLAVE: user
```

y tengo el archivo config/database.yml con el siguiente código:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: prueba_desarrollo  
  #username: user
  #password: user
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USUARIO'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_CLAVE'] %>
```

al levantar el servidor en rails con el comando `rails s` me genera este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    107: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    106: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    105: from /home/elorat/sites/prueba/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    104: from /home/elorat/sites/prueba/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    103: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    102: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    101: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    100: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
     99: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
     98: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
     97: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
     96: from /home/elorat/sites/prueba/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
     95: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     94: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     93: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     92: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
     91: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     90: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
     89: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     88: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
     87: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
     86: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
     85: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
     84: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
     83: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
     82: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
     81: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
     80: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
     79: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
     78: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
     77: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
     76: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
     75: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
     74: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
     73: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
     72: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
     71: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
     70: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
     69: from config.ru:in `<main>'
     68: from config.ru:in `new'
     67: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
     66: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
     65: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
     64: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require_relative'
     63: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     62: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     61: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     60: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
     59: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     58: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
     57: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     56: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
     55: from /home/elorat/sites/prueba/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
     54: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
     53: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
     52: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
     51: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
     50: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
     49: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
     48: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
     47: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
     46: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
     45: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
     44: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
     43: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
     42: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
     41: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
     40: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
     39: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
     38: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
     37: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
     36: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
     35: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
     34: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
     33: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
     32: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
     31: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
     30: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
     29: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
     28: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
     27: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     26: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
     25: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
     24: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
     23: from /home/elorat/sites/prueba/config/initializers/disponibilidad_de_gammu.rb:2:in `<main>'
     22: from /home/elorat/sites/prueba/config/initializers/disponibilidad_de_gammu.rb:3:in `<module:DisponibilidadDeGammu>'
     21: from /home/elorat/sites/prueba/config/initializers/disponibilidad_de_gammu.rb:45:in `<class:Application>'
     20: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/core.rb:161:in `find'
     19: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:75:in `primary_key'
     18: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:87:in `reset_primary_key'
     17: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:99:in `get_primary_key'
     16: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:324:in `table_exists?'
     15: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in `connection'
     14: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:in `retrieve_connection'
     13: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1010:in `retrieve_connection'
     12: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:382:in `connection'
     11: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:523:in `checkout'
     10: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:795:in `acquire_connection'
      9: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:834:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
      8: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:855:in `checkout_new_connection'
      7: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:811:in `new_connection'
      6: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:48:in `postgresql_connection'
      5: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:48:in `new'
      4: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:223:in `initialize'
      3: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:692:in `connect'
      2: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/pg-1.1.3/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
      1: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/pg-1.1.3/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
/home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/pg-1.1.3/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize': FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "elorat", database "prueba_desarrollo", SSL off (PG::ConnectionBad)
elorat@Aspire:~/sites/prueba$
```

Pero cuando pongo los valores directamente en el archivo config/database.yml con el siguiente código:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: prueba_desarrollo  
  username: user
  password: user
```

y ejecuto el comando **`rails s`** se levanta el servidor normalmente

```
elorat@Aspire:~/sites/prueba$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.2 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.3-p105), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Adjunto el archivo config/initializers/variables_de_ambiente.rb por si sirve de algo:

```
module VariablesDeAmbiente
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.before_configuration do
      env_file = Rails.root.join("config", 'variables_de_ambiente.yml').to_s
      if File.exists?(env_file)
        YAML.load_file(env_file)[Rails.env].each do |key, value|
          ENV[key.to_s] = value
        end # end YAML.load_file
      end # end if File.exists?
    end # end config.before_configuration
  end # end class
end # end module
```

Tengo esta configuración en mi PC lubuntu 18.04:

```
elorat@Aspire:~/sites/prueba$ uname -a
Linux Aspire 4.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 14:44:00 UTC 2018 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
elorat@Aspire:~/sites/prueba$ rvm -v
rvm 1.29.7 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
elorat@Aspire:~/sites/prueba$ rails -v
Rails 5.2.2
elorat@Aspire:~/sites/prueba$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [i686-linux]
elorat@Aspire:~/sites/prueba$
```

¡Alguna idea que pueda ser? estoy seguro que es un detalle pero realmente no lo veo!!!  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente es porque no estás cargando las variables de entorno a tiempo para ponerlas en tu archivo `database.yml`. Si lo cargas desde `config/initializers` creo que ya es muy tarde en el ciclo de [inicialización de rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html).

Una opción sería cargar el código de `variables_de_ambiente.rb` en alguna parte de tu archivo `config/application.rb`, aunque personalmente en vez de reinventar la rueda haciendo mi propio código para cargar variables de entorno, preferiría usar una gema administradora de configuración como [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) para manejar `ENV`.